# Can't remove one character of space in my environment

Tags: formatting, environments

The essay I'm working on requires an `abstract` with no abstract title and does not require any indentation. Therefore, I defined the following:

```
\renewenvironment{abstract}
{%
    \par %
    \noindent \begin{bfseries}%
}
{%
    \end{bfseries}%
}
```

However, this following resulted in one character width of space placed in front of my environment `abstract`.

```
\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Quisque gravida varius tellus, nec consequat nulla egestas dapibus. 
Quisque leo justo, pellentesque vehicula nulla commodo, imperdiet egestas turpis. 
Ut iaculis ante in tortor aliquet sodales. 
Nullam et mauris ultrices neque sollicitudin congue quis sed diam. 
Pellentesque blandit hendrerit diam, at cursus nisl eleifend vel. 
Ut non egestas justo, ut semper ex. 
Nullam laoreet purus eu dui elementum, non blandit turpis lacinia. 
Sed eros justo, elementum sit amet dapibus sed, porta a velit. 
Morbi a risus vel nibh bibendum consectetur. 
Ut pharetra, enim non ornare dapibus, ante nibh auctor quam, ut dapibus eros enim quis lectus. 
Suspendisse nec tellus in risus ornare tempus eu eget elit. 
Etiam eu neque scelerisque sem congue consequat vitae ut lectus. 
Curabitur vel est porta, luctus quam ut, posuere tellus.
\end{abstract}
```

Like this: [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Apart from the `\ignorespaces` Steven mentioned, a LaTeX environment already adds a group layer, so you don't need to misuse `\bfseries` as `\begin{bfseries}`...`\end{bfseries}`. Just `\bfseries` at the `\begin` part is enough, and a `\par` in the `\end` part would prevent unexpected behaviour if someone used `\end{abstract}oops`.

Answer (score 7):

Add an `\ignorespaces` at the end of the environment entry point.

Also, `bfseries` is not an environment (to my knowledge) but a declaration: `\bfseries`.  It is automatically terminated by the end of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewenvironment{abstract}
{%
    \par %
    \noindent\bfseries\ignorespaces%
}
{%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Quisque gravida varius tellus, nec consequat nulla egestas dapibus. 
Quisque leo justo, pellentesque vehicula nulla commodo, imperdiet egestas turpis. 
Ut iaculis ante in tortor aliquet sodales. 
Nullam et mauris ultrices neque sollicitudin congue quis sed diam. 
Pellentesque blandit hendrerit diam, at cursus nisl eleifend vel. 
Ut non egestas justo, ut semper ex. 
Nullam laoreet purus eu dui elementum, non blandit turpis lacinia. 
Sed eros justo, elementum sit amet dapibus sed, porta a velit. 
Morbi a risus vel nibh bibendum consectetur. 
Ut pharetra, enim non ornare dapibus, ante nibh auctor quam, ut dapibus eros enim quis lectus. 
Suspendisse nec tellus in risus ornare tempus eu eget elit. 
Etiam eu neque scelerisque sem congue consequat vitae ut lectus. 
Curabitur vel est porta, luctus quam ut, posuere tellus.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Additional to the answer of @StevenB.Segletes have a look to the following mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewenvironment{abstract}
{%
  \par%
  \noindent\bfseries% 
}
{%
  \par%
  \vspace{\baselineskip}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}% <=====================================================
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Quisque gravida varius tellus, nec consequat nulla egestas dapibus. 
Quisque leo justo, pellentesque vehicula nulla commodo, imperdiet egestas turpis. 
Ut iaculis ante in tortor aliquet sodales. 
Nullam et mauris ultrices neque sollicitudin congue quis sed diam. 
Pellentesque blandit hendrerit diam, at cursus nisl eleifend vel. 
Ut non egestas justo, ut semper ex. 
Nullam laoreet purus eu dui elementum, non blandit turpis lacinia. 
Sed eros justo, elementum sit amet dapibus sed, porta a velit. 
Morbi a risus vel nibh bibendum consectetur. 
Ut pharetra, enim non ornare dapibus, ante nibh auctor quam, ut dapibus eros enim quis lectus. 
Suspendisse nec tellus in risus ornare tempus eu eget elit. 
Etiam eu neque scelerisque sem congue consequat vitae ut lectus. 
Curabitur vel est porta, luctus quam ut, posuere tellus.
\end{abstract}
Text.
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting abstract]

With the given definition of environment `abstract` (I only added an `\par\vspace{}` to get a new paragraph after the abstract) you get only an abstract without leading blank, if you add an `%` after `\begin{abstract}`. That means the disturbing blank you got comes from the blanks after command `\begin{abstract}`.

To get rid of it you have two possibilitys:

1. Add the `%` after `\begin{abstract}` as I did in the mwe (and do not forget it!) or better
2. add `\ignorespaces` after `\bfseries` as already shown by Steven ... It also ignores blanks after `\begin{abstract}` ...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in LaTeX mechanism for suppressing the indent in the next paragraph.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}
 {%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}\bfseries
  \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
 }
 {%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Quisque gravida varius tellus, nec consequat nulla egestas dapibus. 
Quisque leo justo, pellentesque vehicula nulla commodo, imperdiet egestas turpis. 
Ut iaculis ante in tortor aliquet sodales. 
Nullam et mauris ultrices neque sollicitudin congue quis sed diam. 
Pellentesque blandit hendrerit diam, at cursus nisl eleifend vel. 
Ut non egestas justo, ut semper ex. 

Nullam laoreet purus eu dui elementum, non blandit turpis lacinia. 
Sed eros justo, elementum sit amet dapibus sed, porta a velit. 
Morbi a risus vel nibh bibendum consectetur. 
Ut pharetra, enim non ornare dapibus, ante nibh auctor quam, ut dapibus eros enim quis lectus. 
Suspendisse nec tellus in risus ornare tempus eu eget elit. 
Etiam eu neque scelerisque sem congue consequat vitae ut lectus. 
Curabitur vel est porta, luctus quam ut, posuere tellus.
\end{abstract}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Quisque gravida varius tellus, nec consequat nulla egestas dapibus. 
Quisque leo justo, pellentesque vehicula nulla commodo, imperdiet egestas turpis. 
Ut iaculis ante in tortor aliquet sodales. 
Nullam et mauris ultrices neque sollicitudin congue quis sed diam. 
Pellentesque blandit hendrerit diam, at cursus nisl eleifend vel. 
Ut non egestas justo, ut semper ex. 
Nullam laoreet purus eu dui elementum, non blandit turpis lacinia. 
Sed eros justo, elementum sit amet dapibus sed, porta a velit. 
Morbi a risus vel nibh bibendum consectetur. 
Ut pharetra, enim non ornare dapibus, ante nibh auctor quam, ut dapibus eros enim quis lectus. 
Suspendisse nec tellus in risus ornare tempus eu eget elit. 
Etiam eu neque scelerisque sem congue consequat vitae ut lectus. 
Curabitur vel est porta, luctus quam ut, posuere tellus.

\end{document}
```

[image]